# Move button randomly on hover: Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, hover

I have a button that I want to move randomly on hover. I want it to be able to move anywhere not pseudorandom, but truly random. The code I have only made the button go to the bottom right.

Also, if possible, if you could make an animation to make the animation smooth, that would be greatly appreciated.

```js
document.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
    x = event.pageX;
    y = event.pageY;
    div.style.left = x + 35 + "px";
    div.style.top = y + 35 + "px";
});
```

Comment: The `mouseover` event listener should be attached to the element you want to hover over, not the entire document.

Comment: Replace `35` with something like `Math.random() * 35` to get a random number between 0 and 35.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an event listener for `mouseover`, then generate random coordinates by using [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) multiplied by [`Window.innerHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight) and [`Window.innerWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth):

```js
$('button').on('mouseover', function() {
  $(this).css({
    'top': Math.random() * window.innerHeight + "px",
    'left': Math.random() * window.innerWidth + "px"
  });
})
```

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Try to click me!</button>
```

To make it smooth, we can use jQuery's [`animate()`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) function:

```js
$('button').on('mouseover', function() {
  $(this).animate({
    'top': Math.random() * window.innerHeight + "px",
    'left': Math.random() * window.innerWidth + "px"
  }, "medium");
})
```

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Try to click me!</button>
```